# Using Ubuntu to install Cardboard SDK for VR applications

Tags: google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am trying to install Cardboard SDK on Ubuntu 14.04 and it say it needs "Unity", but the download of "Unity" seems to be only for Windows and Mac. Anyone has tried this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity3d has already released a [beta Linux version](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/).

It is not perfect, but stable enough. If you want to develop a cardboard app on Ubuntu, you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you, somewhat understandably, confusing  "[Ubunutu's Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/)" with the [Unity - Game Engine](https://unity3d.com/)?

You should take a look at [Programming for Google Cardboard (starting from nothing)](http://dcastro9.blogspot.com/2014/10/programming-for-google-cardboard.html). To quote:

> I assume I have to start fresh, so I went to the generic Google
>   Developer website. I want to program on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine,
>   hopefully that won't be a hurdle but it probably will be.

The developer appears to manage to get it running though.

Comment: The Unity download that I was talking about is here, different from Ubuntu unity: http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download?ref=personal

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a beta version of unity which works for ubuntu.
has a quite of bugs, but can manage.

https://linuxhint.com/install-unity3d-linux/

follow the above link and you are done installing.
after installing try not to work offline as it crashes.

## unity3d #ubuntu